# Difference between Python dictionary comprehension and loop

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I am using Python 3.4, and I am testing out dictionary comprehension.

Let's say I have the following code:

```
listofdict = [{"id":1, "title": "asc", "section": "123"},{"id":2, "title": "ewr", "section": "456"}]
titles1 = []
titles2 = []
titles1.append({r["section"]: r["title"] for r in listofdict})
print("titles1 = " + str(titles1))

for r in listofdict:
  section = r["section"]
  title = r["title"]
  titles2.append({section: title})

print("titles2 = " + str(titles2))
```

I thought both methods should give me the same result, but I get the following instead:

```
titles1 = [{'456': 'ewr', '123': 'asc'}]
titles2 = [{'123': 'asc'}, {'456': 'ewr'}]
```

titles2 is what I actually want, but I want to use dictionary comprehension to do it.

What is the right way to write the dictionary comprehension?

Comment: If you understand exactly how a comprehension (of any kind) maps to an explicit loop around `list.append`/`set.add`/`dict[…]=…`/`yield`, it's a lot easier to debug code like this: just convert it to the explicit loop and see if it's what you wanted. The tutorial section on [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) actually explains it very nicely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use a dict comprehension for that, because a dict comprehension produces **one** dictionary with the keys and values taken from the loop(s).

You'd use a list comprehension instead:

```
[{r["section"]: r["title"]} for r in listofdict]
```

This produces the one dictionary each iteration, producing a new list:

```
>>> listofdict = [{"id":1, "title": "asc", "section": "123"},{"id":2, "title": "ewr", "section": "456"}]
>>> [{r["section"]: r["title"]} for r in listofdict]
[{'123': 'asc'}, {'456': 'ewr'}]
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm! Should have realized I wanted to build a list of dictionaries, so should have used list comprehension.